# Stopping a Windows Update KB3045999 from installing indefinitely on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, windows-update

I have a Windows update I would like to stop from installing.  Every day I come back into my office and Windows Update has re-installed it, and every day I uninstall it.  It's getting to be kind of annoying.

Why would I not want stop installing this update you ask?  Well maybe you ought to [ask Oracle about that](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=67355).

Comment: If you have hidden the update and the update keeps appearing then you are under a group policy, and if thats the case, talk to somebody who can actually configure your system not to install it because you don't have the required permissons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's your own computer, you can open up Windows Update -> Right-Click the update in question -> Hide Update.

If this is an office-managed computer, then you need to work with your IT department to get the update removed.

Comment: There is.  I'm aware of it.  Stupid Windows.

Comment: Well then you're probably best reaching out to your IT department and having them fix the issue.

Comment: well, what kind of answer are you looking for? we can't really tell you how to bypass your companies policy enforcement.

Answer (score -3):

This is a known problem. MS fixed this 2 weeks ago, as far as I can remember.
You can disable automatic update temporarily and tried it again in a few days.

Or, you can install a 3rd party app that installs windows update from their app. I would suggest 360 Total Security. You can google it. They have a Patch Up feature that fetches, downloads and installs Windows updates. I've read before, I guess it was from Softpedia, about this problem and 3rd party apps fixes the never ending updates. One of the 3rd party app is 360 Total Security. There are other apps but I'm only familiar with 360 as Im using it on some of my desktop PCs.

Comment: Please provide reference showing this is a "known problem".  I'm not sure how your answer is supposed to help the OP?

Comment: I tried to find the article from news.softpedia.com but I can't locate it. Though, I'm not sure if I've read that article from softpedia as I can't find it now. I just thought I've read it from softpedia as I access that site everyday to read news of my interests. It might have be from other source, I can't remember.

2nd paragraph was just a suggestion based on what I've read on the article I can no longer locate. 360's Patch Up feature was 2nd or 3rd on the list of apps they mentioned to successfully install the update.